# Saving a Dictionary to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

My app parses podcast RSS feeds. I use 2 entities: Podcasts (to hold podcast-related data) and Episodes (Episodes data like summaries etc). After parsing a feed, I store the list of episodes in an Array called "episodesToDisplay". When a user subscribes to a podcast, I want to save the data held by that array in Core Data. Here is my code which throws an error on the annotated line below:

```
class Podcasts: UITableViewController {
var currentPodcast: Podcasts!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let podcastsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Podcasts", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    let podcastsFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Podcasts")
    var error: NSError?

    let result = self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(podcastsFetch, error: &error) as [Podcasts]?
    if let resu = result {
        println("res is \(resu.count)")
        self.currentPodcast = resu[0] as Podcasts
    } else {
        println("did not work")
    }
}

    @IBAction func subscribe(sender: AnyObject) {
        for dict: AnyObject in episodesToDisplay {
    let episodesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Episodes", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    let episodesToSave = Episodes(entity: episodesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    var episodes = currentPodcast.episode.mutableCopy() as NSMutableOrderedSet
    let btDict = dict as NSDictionary <---------------- Crash
        episodesToSave.title = btDict["title"] as String
        episodesToSave.summary = btDict["summary"] as String
        episodesToSave.link = btDict["link"] as String
        episodes.addObject(episodesToSave)
        currentPodcast.episode = episodes.copy() as NSOrderedSet

    }



    // Save
    var error:NSError?
    if !self.managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("could not save \(error)")
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the error?  If you know that `episodesToDisplay` contains NSDictionaries why are you using AnyObject?

Comment: I get this error: libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
I've removed AnyObject because you are right. However it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: So that error indicates that your array doesn't contain an NSDictionary. Set a breakpoint and use the debugger to see what is actually in your array

Comment: I think you are right. I use MWFeedParser to parse the feed (https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/RootViewController.m). Every time I parse a feed item, I add it to the episodesToDisplay array. However because this array contains MWFeedItem objects, "dict" is considered an MWFeedItem constant. I have no idea how to proceed ahead but still trying. If you have any idea, please let me know!

Comment: So your array will contain `MWFeedItem` objects - simply modify your for loop to retrieve MWFeedItems from the array instead of NSDictionaries and then access the properties from each MWFeedItem

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! If you want to move your last comment to answer, I will upvote it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that your array doesn't contain `NSDictionary` objects - that is why you get dynamic cast exception when you try and access an element `as` an `NSDictionary`.

From your comment it seems that your array actually contains `MWFeedItem` objects, so all you need to do is change your code to use that object type and then you can access the properties of the `MWFeedItem`  -

```
@IBAction func subscribe(sender: AnyObject) {
        for item: MWFeedItem in episodesToDisplay {
    let episodesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Episodes", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    let episodesToSave = Episodes(entity: episodesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    var episodes = currentPodcast.episode.mutableCopy() as NSMutableOrderedSet
        episodesToSave.title = item.title
        episodesToSave.summary = item.summary
        episodesToSave.link = item.link
        episodes.addObject(episodesToSave)
        currentPodcast.episode = episodes.copy() as NSOrderedSet

    }
```