# Swift, save dictionary [String:UIImage] to CoreData for beginner

Tags: swift, dictionary, core-data

I'm a totally newbie in CoreData, can someone please explain me how to save a dictionary [String:UIImage] in coredata, for caching purposes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a Dictionary to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749298/saving-a-dictionary-to-core-data)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/storing-dictionaries-in-core-data/18877)

Comment: I recommend you to use kingfisher lib.